# How to change line color in EditText

Tags: android, xml, layout, styles

I am creating an EditText in my layout xml file

But I want to change color line in EditText from Holo to (for example) red.
How that can be done?

[image]

Answer (score 387, accepted):

This is the best tool that you can use for all views and its FREE many thanks to @[Jérôme Van Der Linden](http://mailto:jeromevdl@android-holo-colors.com).

The Android Holo Colors Generator allows you to easily create Android components such as `EditText` or spinner with your own colours for your Android application. It will generate all necessary nine patch assets plus associated XML drawable and styles which you can copy straight into your project.

> http://android-holo-colors.com/

**UPDATE 1**

This domain seems expired but the project is an open source you can find here

> https://github.com/jeromevdl/android-holo-colors

try it

this image put in the background of `EditText`

```
android:background="@drawable/textfield_activated"
```

[image]

---

**UPDATE 2**

For API 21 or higher, you can use `android:backgroundTint`

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Underline color change"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
```

---

**Update 3**
Now We have with back support `AppCompatEditText`

**Note:** We need to use **app:backgroundTint** instead of **android:backgroundTint**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:hint="Underline color change"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/blue_gray_light" />
```

**Update 4**
AndroidX version

```
  <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText

    app:backgroundTint="@color/blue_gray_light" />
```

Comment: Link seems dead? Is the software still available?

Comment: @CodingJohn this project is open sourced you can find here https://github.com/jeromevdl/android-holo-colors

Comment: and does who say that we have to use "app:backgroundTint instead of android:backgroundTint"??

Comment: if you want *backward compatibility* then you can use app:*** OW android: ***

Comment: app:backgroundTint overrides android:background in the widget, if you want to change both you will have to set the background in a FrameLayout wrapper.

Answer (score 235):

I don't like previous answers. The best solution is to use:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText

      app:backgroundTint="@color/blue_gray_light" />
```

`android:backgroundTint` for `EditText` works only on **API21+** . Because of it, we have to use the support library and `AppCompatEditText`.

Note: we have to use `app:backgroundTint` instead of `android:backgroundTint`

**AndroidX version**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText

      app:backgroundTint="@color/blue_gray_light" />
```

Comment: This is the best solution! Simple and works on all API levels. Thanks!

Comment: you don't need that, if you use the appcompat library EdtiTexts are automatically transformed into AppCompatEditText and the background tint applied.

Comment: I think this should be exactly solution

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked for API 16+. Best Solution.

Comment: possible to set app:backgroundTint programatically? I could find a method 'setBackgroundTint'

Comment: background tint changes the entire background tint, not the underline

Comment: @Code Widget: wrap the AppCompatEditText in a FrameLayout, then you can set the background in the FrameLayout and it won't be affected by the backgroundTint in the AppCompatEditText.

Answer (score 80):

You can also quickly change the EditText's underline color by tinting the background of the EditText like so:

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Something or Other"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
```

Comment: Only works in API 21 or higher. Any way to make this work for lesser API level?

Comment: Check reVerse solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574328/changing-edittext-bottom-line-color-with-appcompat-v7

Comment: @mladj0ni Cool, +1d

Comment: For lesser api levels, use only "backgroundTint" instead of "android:backgroundTint" 
Credits https://stackoverflow.com/a/29400711/1590911

Comment: this changes the entire background color, not the line color

Answer (score 48):

for **API** below 21, you can use theme attribute in `EditText` 
put below code into style file

```
<style name="MyEditTextTheme">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

use this style in `EditText` as

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/user_input_field_height"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:hint="@string/password_hint"
    android:theme="@style/MyEditTextTheme"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

Comment: do you know how to add alpha/opacity to the style file? Like it should take the normal color with an opacity and once they start typing, it should take the activated or highlighted color

Comment: @ANS for that you need to add a text watcher listener and set the opacity in "onTextChanged" method dynamically

Comment: oh. So it cannot be added to the styling or selector file and should be done dynamically?

Comment: @ASN opacity is added in hex color i the first two characters 00-FF so for instance: #A1FAFAFA

Answer (score 26):

Programmatically, you can try:

```
editText.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: Best answer for Xamarin.Forms effect

Answer (score 16):

Its pretty simple (Required: Minimum API 21)...

1. Go to your xml and select the EditText field
2. On the right side, you can see the 'Attributes' window. Select 'View All Attributes'
3. Just search for 'tint'
4. And add/change the 'backgroundTint' to a desired color hex (say #FF0000)

[image]

[image]

Keep Coding........ :)

Comment: Minimum API 21.

Comment: Changing the background tint changes the BACKGROUND. This answer is incorrect

Answer (score 15):

You can change the color of EditText programmatically just using this line of code:`edittext.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(yourcolor));`

Comment: That's what I'm looking for ! Thx

Comment: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                editText.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE));
            }

Answer (score 11):

i think the best way is by theme:

```
<style name="MyEditTextTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/action_blue</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/action_blue</item>
</style>

<style name="AddressBookStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
     <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
     <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
     <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
     <item name="android:theme">@style/MyEditTextTheme</item>
</style>

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            style="@style/AddressBookStyle"/>
```

Comment: this doesnt work for me with style tag but with android:theme tag

Answer (score 9):

To change Edittext’s underline color:

If you want the entire app to share this style, then you can do the following way.

(1) go to styles.xml file. Your AppTheme that inherits the parent of Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar (in my case) will be the base parent of all they style files in your app. Change the name of it to “AppBaseTheme’. Make another style right under it that has the name of AppTheme and inherits from AppBaseTheme that you just edited. It will look like following:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!--see http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette-->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_brown_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/material_brown_700</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/flamingo</item>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Then change the “colorAccent” to whatever the color you want your EditText line color to be.

(2) If you have other values folders with style.xml, this step is very important. Because that file will inherit from your previous parent xml file. For example, I have values-19/styles.xml. This is specifically for Kitkat and above. Change its parent to AppBaseTheme and make sure to get rid of “colorAccent” so that it doesn’t override the parent’s color. Also you need to keep the items that are specific to version 19. Then it will look like this.

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 7):

The line's color is defined by `EditText`'s background property. To change it you should change the `android:background` in the layout file.

I should note that this style is achieved by using a 9-patch drawable. If you look in the SDK, you can see that the background of the `EditText` is this image:

[image: textfield_activated_holo_light.9.png]

To change it you could open it in an image manipulation program and color it in desired color. Save it as `bg_edit_text.9.png` and then put it in you drawable folder. Now you can apply it as a background for your `EditText` like so:

```
android:background="@drawable/bg_edit_text"
```

Answer (score 5):

**drawable/bg_edittext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/colorDivider" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Set to EditText**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_edittext"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

in xml layout use:

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
```

or in java code copy this method:

```
public void changeLineColorInEditText(EditText editText, int color) {
        editText.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
    }
```

and use it like this:

```
changeLineColorInEditText(editText, getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
```

Answer (score 4):

The background of widgets are **API level dependent**.

**ALTERNATIVE 1**

You can provide a custom image to your `EditText` background by

```
android:background="@drawable/custom_editText"
```

Your image should look something like this. It will give you the desired effect.

[image]

**ALTERNATIVE 2**

Set this xml to your `EditText` background attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
<solid android:color="#4C000000"/>
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
             android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
             android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
             android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

This will have the same look and feel of your `EditText` on every API.

Comment: I'm interested in version 4.0 and above. That is, I just want to change the line color when active EditText

Answer (score 4):

You can change the color with tinting the  background
    
`<EditText
    android:backgroundTint="@color/red"/>`

Comment: this works only for api >21 you should follow @Rahul answer for all apis or add different layouts for api >21 in layout-21 folder

Answer (score 3):

Use this method.. and modify it according to ur view names. This code works great.

```
 private boolean validateMobilenumber() {
            if (mobilenumber.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() || mobilenumber.getText().toString().length() < 10) {
                input_layout_mobilenumber.setErrorEnabled(true);
                input_layout_mobilenumber.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_mobilenumber));
               // requestFocus(mobilenumber);
                return false;
            } else {
                input_layout_mobilenumber.setError(null);
                input_layout_mobilenumber.setErrorEnabled(false);
                mobilenumber.setBackground(mobilenumber.getBackground().getConstantState().newDrawable());
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a flat line, you can do this easily with xml. Here is the xml example:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:top="-1dp"
        android:left="-1dp"
        android:right="-1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"
        >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#6A9A3A"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Replace the shape with a selector if you want to provide different width and color for focused edittext.

Comment: with material design it creates rectangle, with wider bottom line

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to use an `AppCompatEditText` with `backgroundTint` attribute of `app` namespace. i.e.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"      
    app:backgroundTint="YOUR COLOR"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

when we use `android:backgroundTint` it will only work in API21 or more but `app:backgroundTint` works on all API levels your app does.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it dynamically if you have custom class for edittext.

First of all you have declare state and color of edittext given below.

```
int[][] states = new int[][]{
                new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_focused}, // enabled
                new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused}, // disabled
        };
        int[] colors = new int[]{
                secondaryColor,
                primaryColor,
        };
```

Then Create ColorStateList variable with that

```
ColorStateList myList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
```

Then last step is to assign it to edittext.

```
editText.setBackgroundTintList(myList);
```

After this you have to written on focused change event.

```
this.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                        setUnderlineColor(selectionColor,deselectionColor);
                    }
                });
```

And you can make above code inside setUnderlineClor() Method,

```
private void setUnderlineColor(int primaryColor, int secondaryColor) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        int[][] states = new int[][]{
                new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_focused}, // enabled
                new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused}, // disabled
        };
        int[] colors = new int[]{
                secondaryColor,
                primaryColor,
        };
        ColorStateList myList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
        setBackgroundTintList(myList);
    }
}
```

Comment: guys setOnFocusChangeListener() method is important cause after selection it wont work and it will take primary color or colorAccent of your application ..

Answer (score 1):

Use android:background property for that edittext. Pass your drawable folder image to it.
For example,

```
android:background="@drawable/abc.png"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_password_tlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:textColorHint="#9e9e9e"
        android:backgroundTint="#000"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:drawableTint="#FF4081"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/UnderLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_password_tlay"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#03f94e" />
```

**it one of doing with view **

Answer (score 1):

Try the following way, it will convert the bottom line color of EditText, when used as a background property.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:left="@dimen/spacing_neg"
        android:right="@dimen/spacing_neg"
        android:top="@dimen/spacing_neg">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="@dimen/spacing_1"
                android:color="@android:color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can simply be done by including this `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay` as attribute in for your editText
and add this `<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />` to your styles