# Material design for subclass of EditText

Tags: android, material-design

In API 21, we can use `colorAccent` to change the color of widgets like `EditText`, `RadioButton` etc. But it doesn't apply to the subclasses of those widgets. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574328/changing-edittext-bottom-line-color-with-appcompat-v7) but it's just like `colorAccent`, it applies only to original widgets.

Is there any solution to this? other than having to create a custom drawable then implements it as a style..

Comment: What do you mean by "subclass of EditText"? Are you saying that if you extend EditText then colorAccent doesn't apply?

Comment: @Squonk yup..I made a custom EditText by extending the original EditText, but the colorAccent doesn't apply to my custom EditText.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually as of Android support 22.1 you should subclass AppCompatEditText.

Comment: This solution crashes on Marshmallow.

Comment: No it does not, maybe you are doing something different.

Answer (score 12):

For applying colorAccent just extend your custom EditText class from 
`android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText`

Comment: @DarkLeonhart this class is for internal use of support library, but i don't know another way

Answer (score 0):

Since, you did not post any source code I'm guessing you're not inflating your view from an XML layout but rater calling new MyCustomEditText.

As the developers site stated: The material theme design can only be applied when loading views using a layout inflater.

This is because the new material design backport hooks into the layout inflation process.

Another reason could be do to the fact that the appcompat v7 library only loads the material design when it finds an EditText in the XML layout. And it does not recognize custom view components.

Google plans to release the Material backport widgets in to the public, they stated that these are currently still in development. You may want to override these special backport widgets it could possibly solve your problem. But since they are not public yet... you can't.

Comment: I did called my custom view through xml and inflate it via onCreateView..so I guess I need to wait then?