# Changing tint color of Android EditText programmatically

Tags: android

I am trying to change the tinting color of an `EditText` View programmatically during runtime. Basically i want to change what you would usually apply as `?attr/colorControlNormal` like in the [default background drawable](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-wear-5.0.0_r1/core/res/res/drawable/edit_text_material.xml).

Changing the background tint does not correctly apply by just setting a `new ColorsStateList` with one color:

`editText.setBackgroundTintList( ColorStateList.valueOf( color ) );`

For one the result is applied to all `EditText` although the tint list is applied and internally mutates the drawable. Also the alpha as specified in the default background [1](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-wear-5.0.0_r1/core/res/res/drawable/edit_text_material.xml) is visible at the beginning.

Here is the outcome of setting the tint color on just the first `EditText`:

[image: outcome of setting the tint color on just the first EditText]

So my question would be: How can I properly apply the tint programmatically to an `EditText`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With the newly introduced `android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat#setTint` setting the color is now possible.

Comment: Show me a example?

Comment: Example: `DrawableCompat.setTint(editText.getBackground(), ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.xxx));`

Comment: How do you reset the background color to default with this? If I use the same code again but with the original color (e.g. `ColorAccent`), the text field uses that color even when it's inactive (usually it would be grey then). If I call `editText.setBackground(oldBackground)`, the `EditText` ends up using the old color when it's inactive and the new one when it's active, so a mix between both.

Answer (score 47):

This works for me:

```
editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color),
                                        PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Source: [Changing EditText bottom line color with appcompat v7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574328/changing-edittext-bottom-line-color-with-appcompat-v7)

Comment: If you want to only temporarily change the color of a single `EditText` (e.g. for marking an error), you have to call `mutate()` too (so: `editText.getBackground().mutate()....`). Otherwise the color change is shared across multiple `EditTexts` and resetting (having saved the old `Background` first) makes the old and the new color mix in a weird way.

Answer (score 14):

Try to create a custom `EditText` and add `this.setBackgroundTintList( ColorStateList.valueOf( color ) );` into constructor.

Comment: Changing the tint during creation time is not sufficient for my use case. I need to change it on the fly during runtime.

Comment: So you can create a listener into the custom `EditText` and call this method whenever you desire.

Comment: That would create a new View each time i change the color which would also require to port over all the state the TextView currently has. That sounds like a lot of overhead.

Comment: No. That wouldn't create a new View. You must create a custom `EditText` with a listener to change its own color. After that, when you want to change the color, you just have to call the listener and every single `EditText` will response this listener.

Comment: I am not following your train of thought. When you specify to set something in the constructor, the only way to call this code again is via instantiation.

Comment: Yes, I said that. But you said that the `EditText` would change their color during creation time. Because of that, I told you to create a listener, but the listener cannot be created into constructor. In this case, you must create it into your class such as usual method.

Answer (score 6):

`setColorFilter` not working for me. I used:

```
Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(mView.getBackground());
DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
mView.setBackgroundDrawable(wrappedDrawable);
```

or

```
DrawableCompat.setTint(mView.getBackground(), ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red));
```

Let's try.

Answer (score 2):

for Kotlin

```
editText.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(R.color.colorLightGray )
```

Answer (score -3):

I wrote a small component to achieve this behavior.

Few important notes:

- Old school `setColorFilter` method is used
- To make tint work, first switch focus to other view, then tint `EditText` background drawable

Usage

```
ErrorLabelLayout layoutPassError = (ErrorLabelLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutPasswordError)
layoutPassError.setError("Password_is_wrong");
// when you want to clear error e.g. in on text changed method
layoutPassError.clearError();
```

XML

```
<com.view.material.ErrorLabelLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutPasswordError"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="Enter your password"/>
</com.view.material.ErrorLabelLayout>
```

Source

```
public class ErrorLabelLayout extends LinearLayout implements ViewGroup.OnHierarchyChangeListener {

    private static final int ERROR_LABEL_TEXT_SIZE = 12;
    private static final int ERROR_LABEL_PADDING = 4;

    private TextView mErrorLabel;
    private Drawable mDrawable;
    private int mErrorColor;

    public ErrorLabelLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView();
    }

    public ErrorLabelLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView();
    }

    public ErrorLabelLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {
        setOnHierarchyChangeListener(this);
        setOrientation(VERTICAL);
        mErrorColor = Color.parseColor("#D32F2F");
        initErrorLabel();
    }

    private void initErrorLabel() {
        mErrorLabel = new TextView(getContext());
        mErrorLabel.setFocusable(true);
        mErrorLabel.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        mErrorLabel.setTextSize(ERROR_LABEL_TEXT_SIZE);
        mErrorLabel.setTextColor(mErrorColor);
        mErrorLabel.setPadding(dipsToPix(ERROR_LABEL_PADDING), 0, dipsToPix(ERROR_LABEL_PADDING), 0);
    }

    public void setErrorColor(int color) {
        mErrorColor = color;
        mErrorLabel.setTextColor(mErrorColor);
    }

    public void clearError() {
        mErrorLabel.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
        mDrawable.clearColorFilter();
    }

    public void setError(String text) {
        mErrorLabel.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        mErrorLabel.setText(text);
        // changing focus from EditText to error label, necessary for Android L only
        // EditText background Drawable is not tinted, until EditText remains focus
        mErrorLabel.requestFocus();
        // tint drawable
        mDrawable.setColorFilter(mErrorColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildViewAdded(View parent, View child) {
        int childCount = getChildCount();
        if (childCount == 1) {
            mDrawable = getChildAt(0).getBackground();
            addView(mErrorLabel);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildViewRemoved(View parent, View child) {
    }

    private int dipsToPix(float dps) {
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                dps, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

Tested on API 16 / 21 with `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1` library.