# Android Change Color of EditText Accent via Java When Active & Not Active

Tags: java, android, colors, android-edittext, diacritics

I have been using the code below that I got from another question to split into two lines to edit the color programmatically.

[Changing tint color of Android EditText programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303112/changing-tint-color-of-android-edittext-programmatically)

```
((EditText) row1.getVirtualChildAt(i))
```

The below code is what I'm using after the above line to change the color.

```
.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.Green), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Right now it sets the underline color so its always green whether or not the EditText box is being used.

How can I set it so it goes back to the default color after I click away from the EditText box. I would also be fine with specifying another color as the default like a light gray color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following the answer that was given here:
[How do I create ColorStateList programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543186/colorstatelist-android-programmatically)

I did change a few things around as order DOES matter and it took a moment to realize this.

Placed the below code block right at the beginning of MainActivity.

```
int[][] states = new int[][] {
        new int[] { android.R.attr.state_focused}, // enabled
        //new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // disabled
        //new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
        new int[] { android.R.attr.state_window_focused}  // pressed
};

int[] colors = new int[] {
        Color.GREEN,
        //Color.BLUE,
        //Color.YELLOW,
        Color.GRAY
};

ColorStateList myColorAccentList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
```

Then placed my statement in my for loop where it was needed.

```
((EditText) row1.getVirtualChildAt(i)).setBackgroundTintList(myColorAccentList);
```

For anyone else you will probably just want to add this part at the end of your edittext.

```
.setBackgroundTintList(myColorAccentList);
```

Comment: Even this does not work for me. When I click on EditText, it gets color from theme - accentColor.

Answer (score 0):

You can register your edit text with OnFocusChangeListener.java and on focus change you can change the color.

```
void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
if(hasFocus){
// color while typing
}else{
// color when clicked away
}

}
```

Comment: How can this work with using ((EditText) row1.getVirtualChildAt(i)).getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.Green), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);  It requires variable i to be declared as final as its in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can create color selector xml for different edit text states that you want to add in the res/color/your_edittext_color_state.xml folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#YOUR_COLOR"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#ANY_COLOR"/>
    <item android:color="#DEFAULT_COLOR"/>
</selector>
```

Then you can set the foregroundTint in your code

editText.setForegroundTintList(getApplicationContext().getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.your_edittext_color_state));

Comment: I created a folder called color and created a xml resource as described above but the below line dosn't seem to change anything. ((EditText) row1.getVirtualChildAt(i)).setForegroundTintList(getApplicationContext().getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.your_edittext_color_state));

Also getColorStateList is depreciated by the way. Is there something newer that would be better?

Comment: Did you change the color in the xml above? For ColorStateList you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543186/colorstatelist-android-programmatically