# Android colorControlNormal xml attributes doesn't work pre-Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-support-library, android-appcompat, material-design

I've been trying to change the color of the `EditText` line on the bottom, but my `EditText` still doesn't wanna change the color, but it's using the style from `Material`.

I've tried to change the color following these answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26631227/3008340)

So I have an `EditText` with the `Material` form but not the colors I've set.

I've put `appcompat-v7` in my `Gradle` config file, and it's already working for the color primary.

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme.MiddleTheme.Widget.EditText" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/middle_primary</item>
    <!-- Those 3 lines are staying in red war in IntelliJ but it does build the project -->
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/middle_sqool_primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/middle_sqool_primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/middle_sqool_primary</item>            
</style>
```

Comment: Did you try removing `android:` from the item names? Just like in `colorPrimary`

Comment: Yes, I did, it removed the red warning within the IDE, but it still doesn't makes changes on the view (once run)

Comment: Did you find a solution? I got the same problem?

Comment: @GrahamBorland Consider creating an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @zlgdev have to tried setting this `style` with `EditText` or with `Activity` theme. Ideally you have to set this `style` to your `EditText` like this 'style="@style/AppBaseTheme.MiddleTheme.Widget.EditText"'

Answer (score 8):

You have to set the `colorControlActivated`, `colorControlHighlight` and `colorControlNorma`l in your **app theme** (or activity theme) not in your edittext style.

Something like this:

```
<style name="Theme.App.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/middle_sqool_primary</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/middle_sqool_primary</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/middle_sqool_primary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This doesn't makes any changes.

Comment: Are you sure that your activity is using this style?

Comment: So to style textColor I would have to override the EditText style, but colorControlNormal in the app theme.  This leaves style that relate to the same control in 2 different styles.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, try using `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText` rather than `EditText`. You should always use that for programmatically created views.

Pretty sure you made it, but be sure you are editing themes in the `values` folder and not in the `values-v21` one (if any).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Wanted to change the highlight colour of the menu items. And none of these attributes didn't work (Support Library v25.0.0).

The only attribute that allowed me to change colour on Pre-L devices is this:

```
<item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/YOUR_DRAWABLE</item>
```

I stopped searching for further workarounds because it's obvious that Support Library is NOT ready for production code.