# Cannot set colorControlNormal and android:textColor in style

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design, android-theme, android-styles

I am trying to style a material `EditText` view:

```
<style name="AppTheme.EditText" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#8AFFFFFF</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Then I apply the style on my theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme">
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.EditText</item>
</style>
```

And apply theme to activity:

```
  <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

However this is not changing the underline color.

I know that I can change the accentColor to change the underline color, but I don't want to do that as I need my accent color to be different for some of the other controls.

Can I style the control underline color like this?

Comment: Is the View being altered anywhere else in the Java code programmatically? (Other than the xml you listed here)

Comment: Nothing is programmatically changing the style/theme/color.

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but are you applying the Theme to the relevant Activity (or to the entire project)? It doesn't seem like your style changes are affecting anything if it's not even affecting the TextColor.

Comment: @LukeWaggoner not a dumb question :)  I added how I apply that theme to the activity to the question.

Comment: What happens, when you apply the style directly to `EditText` in .xml by `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.EditText"?`

Comment: Sorry the text color does change, I was wrong.  The underline color does not.  I updated the question.

Comment: Ok, so you're trying to change the color of the line at the bottom of the EditText? The word "underline" was kinda throwing me a bit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28888373/2949612

Comment: @pRaNaY that leaves the textColor style in the EditText style override and the control color in my AppTheme, meaning same control 2 styles are in 2 different places.  Got to be a better way.

Comment: Another option would be to create a theme extending *ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light* (or the dark one if you need it): *<style name="ThemeTheEditText" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/desiredColor</item>
    </style>* and apply it to the desired EditTexts directly using the *android:theme* attribute.

Comment: @lostintranslation check my answer :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Reason it is not working:**
`colorControlNormal` is an attr of the **theme** while `android:textColor` is a **style** attribute. To change `colorControlNormal`, you have to override a **Theme**, to change `android:textColor` value, you have to override a **style**. There is no attributes named `colorControlNormal` in `@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText` or any parents of it. Therefore, you are overriding nothing when doing this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.EditText" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

**Solution:**
To actually change the value of `colorControlNormal`, you have to change it in a theme. To do that without changing the activity's theme, you can:

1/ Create a ThemeOverlay with only the theme attributes that you wish to change:

```
<style name="AppTheme.EditText"> 
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

2/ Use it only in the your `EditText` view:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.EditText"
/>
```

What is actually happening here is that the View's theme attributes (if exists) will be used. The activity's theme will be used as fallback.

You can always change `colorControlNormal` of the activity's theme to affect the whole activity.

Comment: Is there a way to apply the EditText theme to all widgets in the app? Setting it in the App Theme maybe?

Comment: You can set the editTextStyle attribute in the theme. By default, it is  `@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText` `<item name="editTextStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText</item>`

Comment: I was referring to the a theme that you can apply to an `EditText`.

Comment: Yes. setting it in the app theme will work. Or in other words, setting the app theme atrributes

Comment: really it just works with the properties of controls. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here you go just follow the below steps and you are done.

Step 1: Create Style

Setting the `android:textCursorDrawable` attribute to @null should result in the use of `android:textColor` as the cursor color.

```
<style name="editTextTheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText">

        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>

        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>

        <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>

    </style>
```

Step 2: Use that style as a Theme

```
<style name="MyTheme">
        <item name="theme">@style/editTextTheme</item>
</style>
```

Step 3: implement that theme in your component

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        style="@style/MyTheme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is worked for me. sIt simply consists of overriding the value for `colorControlActivated`, `colorControlHighlight` and `colorControlNormal` in your edittext style theme. Other think is if your want to change the cursor color also then `android:textCursorDrawable` use this property. I put this edittext style in `style.xml(v21)` also.Then, think to use this theme for whatever activity you desire. Below is an example:

> First Solution

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <!--Edittext theme -->
        <item name="editTextStyle">@style/App_EditTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="App_EditTextStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/black</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>

    <item name="android:backgroundTint" >@color/white</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/white</item>

    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

> Other Solution

You can set this by programmatically also. Here is the solution for API < 21 and above

```
Drawable drawable = yourEditText.getBackground(); // get current EditText drawable 
    drawable.setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP); // change the drawable color

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
        yourEditText.setBackground(drawable); // set the new drawable to EditText
    }else{
        yourEditText.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable); // use setBackgroundDrawable because setBackground required API 16
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your style.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/MyEditTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyEditTextStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF0</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.MyEditTextTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#8AFFFFFF</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">#FF0</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#FF0</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#FF0</item>
</style>
```

Then apply **MyEditTextTheme** as a theme for your EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.MyEditTextTheme"/>
```

Now you have yellow underline only at this EditText. Also you can change colorAccent in the MyEditTextTheme, it will not change AppTheme's colorAccent value.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of the underline by doing the following:

```
<style name="AppTheme.EditText" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#8AFFFFFF</item>

    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/white</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

You should really put the `item` with the `android` namespace in its own `styles-v21.xml` file to avoid Android Studio warnings, but it's not 100% necessary. I tested this in an API 19 emulator and it worked just fine, no crashes.

Comment: thanks.  I do see a problem in that only changes the underline color, but the cursor and cursor pointer are still the accentColor.  Which is what colorControlActivated is supposed to change.

Comment: of note, if I put colorControlActivated in the AppTheme and not inside the EditText style it works.  But then I have styling for that control (text color and control color) in 2 different styles.

Comment: Add this: `android:textCursorDrawable="@null"` and it will change the color of the cursor to the text color.

Comment: If you're setting `accentColor` on your entire project or activity, I believe that that will override your `ColorControlActivated` attribute. Not positive. Try adding 3 copies of your current `colorControl` attributes with the `android` namespace.