# What style attribute do I use to change the color of an EditText's focused bottom line?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-styles

I'm trying to change the color of the bottom line from the focused `EditText` in my style.

When I start editing text the color of the bottom line changes to a teal in the `appcompat.Light` them. I'm wondering what attribute this color comes from.

Also I'm supporting back to API 14 so I can't use the tint colors.

Comment: Maybe helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574328/changing-edittext-bottom-line-color-with-appcompat-v7

Answer (score 0):

You can change this color in xml with this line:

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
```

You can change it in code with something like:

```
editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

You can also change this everywhere in your app by adding this line to you style in your themes.xml file:

```
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/blue</item>
```

Comment: These all require a min of API 21 since it was the first to tint widgets this way