# Change color of EditText android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-styles

I have an EditText on Dark background. 
My EditTexts are of black color only(if not focused), so not visible properly.
How can I change the color?
Below is the screenshot.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: design one image file like this and set it as bottomdrawable for textview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is about the Android theme stuff.Maybe you should set your theme's `colorControlNormal` value.Just like below:

```
<style name="Theme.App.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#YOUR COLOR HEER</item>
</style>
```

reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26631227/669647).

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the AppCompat library? If yes you can override the style attributes `colorControlNormal`, `colorControlActivated` and `colorControlHighlight`.

For example:

```
<style name="Theme.App.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/your_color_1</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/your_color_2</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/your_color_3</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this might be help you

```
      <EditText
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
            android:id="@+id/username"
            style="@style/EditUnderBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="@string/hint_email" />
```

Add this at your style.xml

```
 <style name="EditUnderBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.TextView">
    <item name="android:drawableBottom">@drawable/under_bar</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

Add this your drawable

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
  <size android:width="1000dp" android:height="1dp" />
  <solid
     android:color="@color/white"/>
  </shape>
```

If it not work then add this also

```
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/iron</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

its work for me

Its might be help you.Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: Nope, full rectangle is getting white

Comment: so, you need to change the color of a line? Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Or try:

```
android:backgroundTint:”@color/colorWhite”
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to change line color in edittext is to write this in your xml file:

API >= 21:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="YOUR COLOR" />
```

API < 21:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:backgroundTint="YOUR COLOR" />
```