# How to customize EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need the EditText to look like so:

[image: EditText]

I have a color for the bottom line.
I did not work with UI for a long time and I don't remember how to do it.

Does anybody know?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574328/changing-edittext-bottom-line-color-with-appcompat-v7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below `drawable resource` as `background` for `EditText`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" /> <!--background color of box-->

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:top="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:left="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/bg_color" />  <!-- color of stroke -->
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Great thanks for the answer! It works like a charm))

Answer (score 0):

In design support library a new element called **TextInputLayout** was introduced to display the floating label on EditText.

TextInputLayout takes the value of `android:hint` assigned to EditText and displays it as floating label.

To display it like you want, *try this way :*

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/yourThemeWithYourColor">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Email" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following method works for me ( I found this method by looking at [Telegram](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/) source code ) :

1-Create selector like following :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/search_dark_activated" />
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/search_dark_activated" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/search_dark" />
    </selector>
```

And here is nine patch drawables :

[image]
[image]

Comment: One can also get the same 9 patch drawable from **../Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\data\res\drawable** Directory.. Search for **edit_text_material** in this directory.