# How to remove the tint color of EditText or set it to default style in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design, textinputlayout

My default tint Accent color in styles is blue and on error occur im changing it to red programmatically like below code

```
    Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(mUsername.getBackground());
    DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.red_error));
```

But when i restart my app the tint color is red , How do i set it back to default color which is in style.xml ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26631227/2826147

Answer (score 4):

Prefer use colorFilter and not tintcolor for your case :

```
//get reference on drawable
Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(mUsername.getBackground());
//get color ressource with Android M SDK
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    wrappedDrawable.setColorFilter(this.getColor(R.color.blue), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
else
    //classic method
    wrappedDrawable.setColorFilter(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

To remove the filter color, just use clearColorFilter :

```
wrappedDrawable.clearColorFilter();
```

Answer (score 1):

this work for me

```
editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

[Changing EditText bottom line color with appcompat v7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574328/changing-edittext-bottom-line-color-with-appcompat-v7)

Comment: How do i reset it back to default color which is in style.xml.
the problem here is when i restart the app, the bottum line will be always red.
I want it to be default color.