# how to dynamically change the bottom of edit text as the values are entered in android

Tags: android

As i type value in edit text in android i need to change the color of the edit text bottom line to black.

I tried using text watcher but not sure how exactly to change the bottom line color ? Only the line portion below the text should change.

I need to change the edit text color of line below with every input entered. Remaining line color should remain the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing EditText bottom line color with appcompat v7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574328/changing-edittext-bottom-line-color-with-appcompat-v7)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a text watcher to your EditText. After you detect the change you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28433337/4667831) to change the color.

Comment: thanks but could you please explain a bit more how this could be used for changing bottom line color for only the area below the text typed ?

Comment: I dont think you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess with seeker with edit text this can be done

```
<SeekBar android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:max="255"
         android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:padding="10dp"
         android:id="@+id/seekX"></SeekBar>
<EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight=".01"
          android:minWidth="50sp"
          android:maxWidth="50sp"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:padding="10dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
          android:inputType="number"
          android:id="@+id/editX"></EditText>
```