# AutoCompleteTextView strange behaviour in LolliPop Device

Tags: android, android-layout, autocompletetextview, android-design-library, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am using `AutoCompleteTextView` in my layout. But it's `colorControlNormal` and `Activate` is not Working as I expected.

My Color value is `#0072BA`.

Below is figure for Different Device.

**1.) Android Kitkat**

[image]

**2.) Android LolliPop**

[image]

**3.) Android Marshmallow**

[image]

Xml code that i used is below

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/md_black_1000"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="Medical Store Name"
        android:textColorHint="#999999"
        android:layout_below="@+id/search_drug_store"
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView_storename"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="#999999"
    android:layout_below="@+id/autoCompleteTextView_storename"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
```

I am not giving any style to AutoCompleteTextView then Why it's Happening ?

### What I Have Try :

If i give this Style

Reference Material Design link :

http://www.materialdoc.com/autocomplete-view/

and give this style

```
 <style name="Autocomplete" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.AutoCompleteTextView">
    <item name="android:background">@color/green500</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/amber500</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/cyan500</item>
</style>
```

But in Lollipop nothing has Change.

Is this bug in lollipop version or i am doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

actually this is not solution to this problem but you can use this for unique design all over device.
 i have implemented for edittext like this in xml,set background null for edittext and add horizontal line below edittext.

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/newPasswordEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="@null"
        android:textColor="@color/color_black"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:hint="Enter New Password"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleTextView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_below="@+id/newPasswordEditText"
        android:background="@color/color_standard_green" />
```

Comment: I am using `AutoCompleteTextView` not the `EditText` so this is not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no bug in lollipop version you just not override the style of theme with your style,use in this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/26631227/4745569

Comment: This color in editText support theme settings in lollipop,please check if you done it right.