# How to change TextField and Checkboxes color when they have focus/they are checked?

Tags: android, xml, checkbox, colors, textfield

I have a small problem with colors for few elements in my simple application.
As you can see in the image the TextField, when it has focus, and checkboxes, when they are checked, are green, which is the default color.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNMCh.jpg)

This is the code:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
          android:id="@+id/input_name_label"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

          <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:hint="@string/home_text_field"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/input_name"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

and

```
    <CheckBox
          android:text="@string/argInformatica"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/scelta3"
          android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:layout_below="@+id/scelta2"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:visibility="visible" />
```

For the checkboxes I found to add this line to the xml tag

```
    android:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"
```

but it doesn't work as I would like, the checkbox will have accent color also if it is not checked.

Any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: May you please check my answer? let me know if it helps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing EditText bottom line color with appcompat v7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574328/changing-edittext-bottom-line-color-with-appcompat-v7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have this style in your `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="inputColors">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/thirdColor</item> <!-- In focus -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#9e9e9e</item> <!-- not touched -->
</style>
```

Then, to your `CheckBox`/`EditText`, add:

```
android:theme="@style/inputColors"
```

It should work

Answer (score 0):

Into which location (directory/file) do these styles have to go? Regardless of where I tried so far: I am only getting an error that the tag "style" is unknown/illegal... :-(