# Setting dynamically created EditTexts bottom line color programatically?

Tags: android

Pretty much I have an application where you press a `button` and it adds 2 separate `editTexts` to the current `layout` but I am stuck with using a dark background as the default theme has a white underline. I cannot change the color of the `editTexts` and am stuck with a theme color I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you're creating your `EditTexts` dynamically (as you said in your question).

You just have to mutate the background of your newly created `EditText`. This can be achieved as follows:

```
yourEditText.getBackground()
            .mutate()
            .setColorFilter(getColor(R.color.someColor), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

**Related question**

[Changing EditText bottom line color with appcompat v7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574328/changing-edittext-bottom-line-color-with-appcompat-v7)

Comment: Amazing! Works exactly as needed! just getColor is depreciated now though.