# Underline edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext

How can I make permanent underline for an EditText, with ability of color change after being focused?
I haven't found an answer in another topics.
I would like to achieve something like that:
[image]

Comment: have you tried this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/37101446/2632867

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom style for your EditText in `style.xml` like this -

```
<!-- Edit text -->
    <style name="editTextStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/auth_text_paragraph_little</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">left</item>
        <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/editUnderLine</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/hint</item>
    </style>
```

`@color/editUnderLine` is the name of color you want to use from `color.xml` file as like as `string.xml` file and `dimen.xml` file

and use this custom style in your XML layout-

```
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edt_phone_number"
                        style="@style/editTextStyle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/auth_margin_half"
                        android:padding="@dimen/auth_margin_half_plus"
                        android:fontFamily="@string/auth_font_family_regular"
                        android:hint="@string/auth_mobile_number"
                        android:inputType="phone"/>
```