# Change the color of the input line in the alert Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I need to change the color of the edit text line, in the alert dialog, I'm trying everything, and I'm not working.

```
public void alertaComentario()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder comentario = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
        comentario.setMessage("Escreva uma resenha curta");
        final EditText input = new EditText(getActivity());
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        comentario.setView(input);

        comentario.setPositiveButton("Enviar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "A sociedade agradece seu comentário", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        comentario.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        comentario.show();
    }
```

alert dialog

[image]

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Please read [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [changing edittext bottom line color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574328/changing-edittext-bottom-line-color-with-appcompat-v7)

Comment: show us your alert dialog xml

Comment: Share `AppCompatAlertDialogStyle` and tell what color you want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

The line in an editText is usually based on the ColorAccent in the colors.xml:

```
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color> //Change this
```

If you change the color accent, it will change editText color.

Answer (score 0):

in your Alert Dialog xml update `EditText` with this line:

```
 android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
```