# How to display the line regardless of the focused state in a TextInputEditText?

Tags: android, android-textinputedittext

**What is happening**: When i click on `inputName` line is appearing on it

**What I am trying**: To display the line regardless focus is there or not

**Code:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/inputName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/warm_grey"
            android:hint="Enter Mobile Number"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

**Image:**

[image]

I just want to have two colours for focused and unfocused states

Comment: `inputName line is appearing on it` Which line can share any screenshot for the same

Comment: @NileshRathod .... Line appearing is when the `TextInputEditText` gets focus... I posted the image

Comment: you can `requestFocus()` for *inputName* in `onCreate` method.

Comment: can you add activity style also just take Edit text and see

Comment: You probably should use a Custom selector drawable .Cause I am not  sure  if its possible with `Theme` only .

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this properties in your `AppTheme` or just create AnotherTheme and use in your EditText.

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">Color code for default</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">Color code for focused one</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">Color code for focused one</item>
```

**Possibly Duplicate** [Changing EditText bottom line color with appcompat v7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26631227/5305430)

Note:- If you are using the `AppCompat v22` support library, you can specify the theme in the EditText like: `android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Base`. This will ensure the style won't also affect other views in your layouts that you don't want to change.

Comment: This will only Change the color of LIne . Not the Thickness of Line . I think the question is about using same State drawable for Focused and Non Focused state .

Comment: @ADM Where Op mentioned about the Thickness?

Comment: Focused state is about Thickness  and color both . this will only change color . which is already same .

Comment: Ok i see . Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @SushilKumar if you think the question is duplicate don't answer it instead use `VTC` as duplicate

Comment: @Goku how i delete this question ?

Comment: @SushilKumar AFAK you can't because its accepted answer so you can't delete is

Comment: @Goku You mean to close question by marking as duplicate ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`StateListDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#StateList) for this

- A StateListDrawable is a drawable object defined in XML that uses a several different images to represent the same graphic, depending on the state of the object.

**SAMPLE CODE**

> Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Hint Text">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/edt_bg"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Hint Text">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/edt_bg"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

> @drawable/edt_bg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/edt_bg_selected" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/edt_bg_normal" android:state_focused="false" />
</selector>
```

> @drawable/edt_bg_selected

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="-3dp"
        android:right="-3dp"
        android:top="-3dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#0fe4e4" />

            <solid android:color="#00ffffff" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

> @drawable/edt_bg_normal

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="-3dp"
        android:right="-3dp"
        android:top="-3dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#000" />

            <solid android:color="#00ffffff" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**NOTE**

Use **`android:width="2dp"`** and **`android:color="#000"`** as per your requirement to set  Thickness width and color of line in your `TextInputEditText`

Comment: Thank you , I have uprooted it

Comment: @Devrath welcome happy to help u you need to accept this answer because using above code you can able to  Change both the color of LIne and Thickness of Line

Answer (score 0):

This little function may help you

```
fun hintRemover(textInputLayout: TextInputLayout, textInputEditText: TextInputEditText, text: String) {
    textInputEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
        if (hasFocus) {
            textInputLayout.hint = null
        }
        else {
            textInputLayout.hint = text
        }
    }
}
```