# Changing EditText bottom line color android

Tags: android

How can I change the default EditText bottom line color in android ?

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/label_rename_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/rename_label"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"

        />
```

Comment: its not possible without background image or lollipop

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677414/how-to-change-line-color-in-edittext  check this.