# Moving a drawable line

Tags: android, android-edittext, drawable, shapes

I wanted to make the Edit Text line in my app a custom color, so I used a line drawable xml and set that as my Edit Text background, ala [How to change line color in EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677414/how-to-change-line-color-in-edittext/24677522#24677522).

The problem is that my drawn lines are now behaving as strikethroughs, rather than appearing at the bottom of the Edit Text. Is there a way to move them down?

Have tried setting android:gravity on both the Edit Text and the drawable.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncl9H.png

Answer (score 0):

Try Following Code:

```
<LinearLayout
...
android:orientation="vertical">
     <EditText
     ...
     android:background="@null"/>

     <View
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="1dp"
     android:background="@android:color/black"/>
</LinearLayout>
```