# Android. There is no line under one of Plain Text fields

Tags: android, android-studio, android-view

I can't understand why there is no line under one of  Plain Text fields, i have this line in android studio, but when i launch my application on my phone it dissapears. i have tried to copy xml attributes from another plain text view, but it didn't help

1. [How it looks on phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLQiG.jpg).
2. [How it look in android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7TZ3.png)

   ```
   <TableLayout
       android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registration_text_view">

       <TableRow
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/textView3"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:text="@string/nickname_def_text"
               android:textAlignment="center"
               android:textSize="18sp" />

           <EditText
               android:id="@+id/nickname_edit_text"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:autofillHints=""
               android:ems="10"
               android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
               android:textColor="#3A433D" />
       </TableRow>

       <TableRow
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/textView5"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:text="@string/email_def_text"
               android:textAlignment="center"
               android:textSize="18sp" />

           <EditText
               android:id="@+id/email_edit_text"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:autofillHints=""
               android:ems="10"
               android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
               android:textColor="#3A433D" />

       </TableRow>

       <TableRow
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/textView2"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:text="@string/password_def_text"
               android:textAlignment="center"
               android:textSize="18sp" />

           <EditText
               android:id="@+id/password_edit_text"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:autofillHints=""
               android:ems="10"
               android:inputType="textPassword"
               android:textColor="#3A433D" />
       </TableRow>

       <TableRow
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/register_btn"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:text="@string/register_btn"
               android:textColor="#3A433D" />
       </TableRow>

   </TableLayout>
   ```

Comment: Have you tried selecting other `EditText` in launched application to check whether it appears for the first one and hides the selected one's underline? it might be the selector as by default the first `EditText` view get the focus on `Activity` start.

Comment: Yeah, i see, how can i keep this line when EditText in focus?

Comment: Also, check the first `TableRow`, only its height is set as `match_parent`.

Comment: So, does it appear when you select any other `EditText`?

Comment: Yes, this line appears when i select another EditText

Comment: When an `EditText` is selected, the color you set for `colorControlActivated` is used from the theme for the underline which in your case is probably same as the background and not transparent. You can either set a background tint to the `EditText` as `android:backgroundTint="your_color"` or can set a theme to it as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48540695/8244632).

Comment: @LalitFauzdar, yes, problem was in colors, i've made theme for this `EditText` with changed colors and it works.